# How to fire click event after page refresh?

Tags: jquery

I want to fire click event after other page refresh.

The button is on previous page (on which i am applying click event) and I want to show its effect on other page as soon as next page load.

I am using this script but it is working on same page:

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('a').click(function () {
                    alert("fire an event after as soon as next page refresh");
            });
        });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag using window.name and firing the event on page load if the flag is set.
Please remember that window.name is persistent even after moving to another site.